# SELECT em um XML Field

Tags: sql-server, xml

Estou tendo problemas para recuperar o valor de um nó do xml de um campo e preciso da ajuda...

A estrutura da tabela é:

```
--Table Pessoa
   Id int 
   Nome varchar(max)
   DtNascimento date
   Xml_Detalhes XML
```

o meu xml é assim:

```
(1) - Registro de um dos exemplos
<incluir_pessoa xmlns="..." xmlns:ds="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <pessoa>
        <detalhes>
            <nome>FULANO BETA</nome>
            <data_nascimento>1991-11-07</data_nascimento>
        <detalhes>
    <pessoa>
</incluir_pessoa>

(2) - Registro de um dos exemplos
<incluir_pessoa xmlns="..." xmlns:ds="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <pessoa>
        <detalhes>
            <nome>CICLANO CUNHA</nome>
            <data_nascimento>1991-02-20</data_nascimento>
        <detalhes>
    <pessoa>
</incluir_pessoa>
```

E a minha query está assim:

```
SELECT
    P.Id,
    P.DtNascimento,
    P.Xml_Detalhes,
    d.n.value('(nome)[1]','varchar(max)') as NomeXML
FROM 
    Pessoa P
OUTER APPLY
    C.consumoXmlEnvio.nodes('/incluir_pessoa/pessoa/detalhes') as d(n)
```

e o retorno vem como:

```
Id   | Nome    |  DtNascimento  |  Xml               | NomeXML
1    | Fulano  |   1991-11-07   | <incluir_pessoa... | NULL
2    | Ciclano |   1993-02-20   | <incluir_pessoa... | NULL
```

e deveria vir como:

```
Id   | Nome    |  DtNascimento  |  Xml               | NomeXML
1    | Fulano  |   1991-11-07   | <incluir_pessoa... | FULANO BETA
2    | Ciclano |   1993-02-20   | <incluir_pessoa... | CICLANO CUNHA
```

como retornar o nome do xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui na empresa me passaram a solução. Foi necessário definir um namespace para a busca.

Daí a query ficou assim:

```
SELECT
    P.Id,
    P.DtNascimento,
    P.Xml_Detalhes,    
    d.n.value('declare default element namespace "http://../incluir_pessoa.xsd"; (/incluir_pessoa/pessoa/detalhes/nome)[1]','varchar(70)') as NomeXML
FROM 
    Pessoa P
```

Comment: poderia marcar sua resposta como a aceita?